# unknown error for expected primary-expression

Tags: c++, syntax-error

Hello i'm trying to write a text based game and I've gotten this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:48:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
 main.cpp:48:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
```

I have no idea what is causing this so I was hoping that you'd guys could shed some light on it

here's the full source code by the way: http://pastebin.com/XtverEdR

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here. This problem can be expressed with just a `main` function containing one line. This can easily be formed by taking things out as long as the error stays. At that point, you can ask a good question on why it's invalid, or easily search for duplicates of said question.

Comment: for the declaration of the function cls? because i added a semicolon there and i still have the same issue

Comment: i would its just that everything seems 100% right, ill try thou

Comment: gabriel found the issure, but why would a goto tag need semicolon?

Comment: syntax is "label: statement;" [Check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c002fdz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Bob_the_rhino: I think a label is only allowed before a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you there is a missing `;` before a `}`.

In your case, a small example that produces the same result.

```
int main()
{
    goto cont;
  cont:
         //   semi-colon needed here, as a goto label is not a statement, so must be followed by a statement
}
```

It is usually advisable to actually include a minimal sample of code in your post.  Giving a link to another site, as you have done, makes your question completely meaningless in future when that link disappears (which happens frequently in practice).